# Is there a word for values held in such high importance that nothing can compare, or a fact or statement held as a truth above all others?

Tags: word-request

Is there a word for values held in such high importance that nothing can compare, or a fact held as a truth above all others? I am trying to come up with a word or phrase, but can't think of anything that sounds ok.

For example:

> The truth about the Christian God is a ___ above all facts or
>   statements.
>
> Universal suffrage is a ___ above all others.
>
> Freedom of speech is a ___ above all.

Comment: If such a word exist, doesn't it make the "above all" part of your examples redundant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word I can think of for "an idea held as a truth above all others" is [dogma](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dogma). However, it does not fit well into your example sentences.

(But then, what exactly is the truth about the Christian God...?)

Note that the word "dogma" is typically used as a critique by people who don't hold the idea as a undeniable truth or paramount principle.

It seems to me that what you are looking for is a combination of an adjective and a noun, not a single word. Such combinations that I can suggest are

- Paramount principle
- Undeniable right
- Moral axiom

Answer (score -1):

## Above all

Your example sentences use the words “above all”, which helps make it easier to find a word.

In your examples:

> The truth about the Christian God is a ___ above all facts or statements.
>
> Universal suffrage is a ___ above all others.
>
> Freedom of
>   speech is a ___ above all.

“A principle above all”, “a concept above all”, or “a precept above all” certainly work.

Each of these has a slightly different shade of meaning.  The best choice depends on the shade of meaning you need.

For example, in a society undergoing change, someone might say:

> Freedom of
>   speech is a **goal** above all.

In a community debating rules to be placed on people’s conduct, someone might say:

> Freedom of speech is an **inviolable principle** or a **necessity** above all.

Comment: So you have had to do(albeit in a better method) what I did and put interpretation on the examples because they do not work. GOAL, and INVIOLABLE PRINCIPLE have no relation to  "high importance" Although they work in the examples, if you disregard what the authors requirements are. The fact is that. the question was fine till these difficult; nay impossible examples were added.

Answer (score -2):

> Is there a word for values held in such high importance that nothing can compare, or a fact held as a truth above all others?

---

The word paramount meets your description of the word required but I would not be inclined to use it in any of your examples. Sometimes our expectation are difficult to meet. Language, the same as life in general, can be complicated.

For example **You have listed three examples, so which of the three is paramount? because you cannot use paramount in the other two.** Also, PLEASE NOTE, they are subjective not fact.

**There is no easy fit all solution to many questions and everything is relative. I have hopefully pointed this out by the use of controversial answers.**

**paramount**: adjective formal:  more important than anything else:

"The truth about the Christian God is a _**revered**__ above all facts or statements", *by the followers of the Christian faith.*

(*God is_**revered**__ above all others. The truth of facts or statements relating to God are beyond question, to true Christians).*

"Universal suffrage is a _**joke**__ above all others". *The UK is tearing it's self to pieces over this issue because, nearly half the voters in a recent referendum refuse to accept the result.*

"Freedom of speech is a _**dream**__ above all", ***because many countries in the world do not have this right***.

---

> **paramount** more important than anything else: [Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/paramount)

Comment: Blackbird's example is a list of the kind of sentence that the requested word would go into, not a request for a word that would make all three sentences true at the same time. Furthermore, your additions to the sentences are irrelevant, and contain several typos.

Comment: @ Katy Thank you for advising me sometimes it is difficult to concentrate with the twins screaming. I will take a look at it. What happened to your other comments?

Comment: It looks like a moderator has gone through and deleted our previous discussion.

Comment: @Katy pity it was useful as you made some relative points that help clarify things. This editing can be both helpful and unhelpful

Comment: It seems that the OP is asking for a noun, as all 3 cases are preceded by "a". "Paramount" is an adjective.

Comment: @laugh; agreed, did you find it?

Comment: This answer doesn’t work. “Joke” seems to be the opposite of “paramount importance.”  And “a revered” doesn’t make sense.  A noun is needed.  Can you please clean up this answer or try again?

Comment: @ whiskeychief I completely agree  The fact is that. the question was fine till these difficult; nay impossible examples were added. As I stated "There is no easy fit all solution to many questions and everything is relative". I have hopefully pointed this out by the use of controversial answers. On this site there seems to be a stigma attached to controversial statements, that I am sure Shakespeare and his likes would have abhorred as, controversy gives birth to a stimulated debate.